# mysql select values from three dropdown option list and insert in one cell one value dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: mysql, date

what i need is to select value from three dropdown option select and insert in one field/cell in mysql database.
For example, i want to select day, month, year in separate dropdown and all value i want to insert into mysql database in one field, like dd/mm/yyyy.

```
<select>
     <option value="January">January</option>
     <option value="February">February</option>
     <option value="March">March</option>
      ...
     <option value="December">December</option>
</select>
```

the same procedure is for days and years.

```
<select>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
        ...
     <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select>
     <option value="1980">1980</option>
     <option value="1981">1981</option>
     <option value="1982">1982</option>
     ...
     <option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>
```

And i want to get in my database just one field dd/mm/yyyy with all three values selected by user. Thank you.

yes i try this code:

```
<b>Data eliberării:&nbsp;</b><select name="day"><option>Selectează ziua</option>
<?php
for ($day = 1; $day <= 31; $day++) {
echo "<option value=\"$day\">$day</option>\n";
}
$day = $_POST['day'];
echo '';
?>
</select>

<select name="month"><option>Selectează luna</option>
<?php
$months = array (1 => 'Ianuarie', 'Februarie', 'Martie', 'Aprilie', 'Mai', 'Iunie',   'Iulie', 'August', 'Septembrie', 'Octombrie', 'Noiembrie', 'Decembrie');
 foreach ($months as $key => $value) {
echo "<option value=\"$key\">$value</option>\n";
}
$month = $_POST['month'];
echo '';
?></select>

<select name="year"><option>Selectează anul</option>
<?php
 for ($year = 1950; $year <= 2021; $year++) {
echo "<option value=\"$year\">$year</option>\n";
}
$year = $_POST['year'];
$cm_data_elib = $month." ".$day.",".$year; 
echo '';
?>
```

Comment: Can you post some test cases or the code you have tried?

Comment: i post in my question the code what i try. Sorry is in Romanian language year=anul, month=luna, day=ziua

Comment: Then the given answers should work!

Comment: yes working indeed. thank's all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="month">
 <option value="01">January</option>
 <option value="02">February</option>
 <option value="03">March</option>
  ...
 <option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<select name="day">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
    ...
 <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select name="year">
 <option value="1980">1980</option>
 <option value="1981">1981</option>
 <option value="1982">1982</option>
 ...
 <option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>
```

if submit a form get values

```
$day=$_POST['day'];
$month=$_POST['month'];
$year=$_POST['year'];
```

SQl query

```
$dob = $day.'/'.$month.'/'.$year;

$query="insert into tablename (`dob`)values($dob)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Firt use numbers for option values and give a name to each select items.

```
<select name="month">
     <option value="1">January</option>
     <option value="2">February</option>
     <option value="3">March</option>
      ...
     <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

Then assuming that you are using a parameterized query,

```
$date = $_POST["day"] . "/" . $_POST["month"] . "/". $_POST["year"];
$query = "INSERT INTO yourTable (..., `date`, ...) VALUES (..., :date, ...)";
$save = $db->prepare($query);
$save->bindValue(":date", $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$save->execute();
...
```